# safari css bold font too bold

Tags: css, fonts, cross-browser

the first line of font is rendered in Safari, 
and the second line of font is rendered in other browsers.

I think it is a common issue with the bold font rendering in safari. but does any body have a solution to this issue. the font is too bold in safari browser which makes it not so pretty. I try to set the font-weight:normal, then all browser renders the same. but some fonts need to be bold. thanks for help.

[image: safari/chrome,FF,IE bold font]

Comment: the one shown is oswald. but all the fonts have this problem

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is technically nothing you can do about this. [Here's an article on the topic of crappy Safari font smoothing](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2007/06/whats-wrong-with-apples-font-rendering.html)

There are workarounds though

- Use images instead of text
- [Make the font look thinner](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2007/06/whats-wrong-with-apples-font-rendering.html)

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried:

```
-webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
```

This just solved the same issue for me.

Answer (score 1):

In your **global.scss** file

```css
* {
  font-synthesis: none !important;
}
```

[Answer reddit post](https://www.reddit.com/r/Safari/comments/17sa9w9/comment/k8rg7yq/?utm_source=share&utm_medium=web3x&utm_name=web3xcss&utm_term=1&utm_content=share_button)

Comment: I've been stuck on this for a few days and this was it. The variable font I was trying to use would jump in boldness when it went from 599 -> 600. Disabling `font-synthesis` seems to fix it - it increases the weight normally from 599+ (so clearly not missing in the font file) and it prevents the jump in boldness. Thank you!